# Using Gallery beside marquee text

Tags: android

Hi I have a layout that contains

- a gallery
- a textview with .setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);

They do not overlap. Whenever the Marquee ist activated the gallery does not move smoothly and starts to stutter. What is the reason for this and how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your xml so we can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old but maybe more people might stump with this problem like me. Left me scratching my head once I found the marquee was causing the stutters.. looks like an Android bug.

Solved it by not using marquee and using singleLine property only.